# CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f896, Unable to read value from underlying bridge : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-3.0, jrules

I want to execute rules on Rule Execution Server from a Java stand-alone client using an EJB3 rule session.

```
public class TestGameExecute {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Object> inputParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String,Object> resMap = null;
    IlrEJB3SessionFactory ejbSF;
    IlrStatelessSession rs;

    Game game = new Game(10,3);
    inputParameters.put("GAME", game);
    Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    jndiProperties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "corbaloc:iiop:********");
    jndiProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    jndiProperties.put("java.naming.security.principal", "username");
    jndiProperties.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "password");



    try {
        ejbSF = new IlrEJB3SessionFactory(jndiProperties);
        ejbSF.setRemote(true);
        ejbSF.setStatelessRemoteJndiName("ilog.rules.res.session.impl.ejb3.IlrStatelessSessionRemote");
        rs = ejbSF.createStatelessSession();
        IlrSessionRequest request = ejbSF.createRequest();
        request.setRulesetPath(new IlrPath("/GAMLCDDRuleAppPhaseII/SiorkCDDRuleProject_PhaseII"));
        request.setInputParameters(inputParameters);
        request.setForceUptodate(true);
        request.setTraceEnabled(true);
        request.getTraceFilter().setInfoAllFilters(true);
        IlrSessionResponse response = rs.execute(request);
        resMap = response.getOutputParameters();
        Game retGame =(Game)resMap.get("GAME");
        System.out.println(retGame.getWinner());

    } catch (IlrSessionCreationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IlrSessionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And I get this error below:

> > Exception in thread "P=421238:O=0:CT" java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f896 No; nested exception is: 
> >         org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: 
> >     SERVER (id=614476eb, host=gamlwm000t01.esunbank.com.tw) TRACE START:
> >        org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Unable to read value from underlying bridge : Unable to read value from underlying bridge : ClassNotFoundException com.siork.cdd.Game  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 896  completed: No
> >       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.read_value(CDRReader.java:1649)
> >       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.read_abstract_interface(CDRReader.java:1606)
> >       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.read_abstract_interface(CDRReader.java:1591)
> >       at ilog.rules.res.session.impl.ejb3._EJSRemote0SLIlrStatelessSessionEJB3_fdcc75a4_Tie.execute(_EJSRemote0SLIlrStatelessSessionEJB3_fdcc75a4_Tie.java:100)
> >       at ilog.rules.res.session.impl.ejb3._EJSRemote0SLIlrStatelessSessionEJB3_fdcc75a4_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemote0SLIlrStatelessSessionEJB3_fdcc75a4_Tie.java)
> >       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:669)
> >       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:523)
> >       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:523)
> >       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1575)
> >       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3039)
> >       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2922)
> >       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
> >       at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
> >       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
> >     SERVER (id=614476eb, host=gamlwm000t01.esunbank.com.tw) TRACE END.

I have search the soulution about this quest on Internet

Game.java

```
package com.siork.cdd;

import java.io.Serializable;

import ilog.rules.bom.annotations.BusinessName;

public class Game implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static String GAME = "GAME";
private int banker_point;
private int player_point;
private String winner;

public Game() {}

public Game(@BusinessName("BANKER") int banker_point,
            @BusinessName("PLAYER") int player_point) {
    this.banker_point = banker_point;
    this.player_point = player_point;
}
public int getBanker_point() {
    return banker_point;
}
public void setBanker_point(int banker_point) {
    this.banker_point = banker_point;
}
public int getPlayer_point() {
    return player_point;
}
public void setPlayer_point(int player_point) {
    this.player_point = player_point;
}
public String getWinner() {
    return winner;
}
public void setWinner(String winner) {
    this.winner = winner;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Java stand-alone client "TestGameExecute" needs to have com.siork.cdd.Game on it's classpath in order to be able to unmarshall an instance of this class over RMI.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to put Game.java into the proper classpath?

com.siork.cdd
  |_ Game.java  
  |_ TestGameExecute.java  

but I still get the same error

Comment: No, you have to put the compiled class file, Game.CLASS, not the java source file, Game.JAVA on the classpath of your standllone client.  What is the command line you use to invoke the client?  You may find this IBM ODM KnowledgeCenter topic helpful:https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.9.1/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.res.developing/topics/tsk_res_dev_ejb_packag_j2ee.html

Answer (score 0):

Its a JDK issue. 
Check your JDK version, upgrade it, for me it worked whe should be 8.x

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set value to

`List<ColReteral> coll;`

`coll.setId("1");`

`remote.update("id", coll);`

I got error

> CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f896, Unable to read value from underlying bridge
> : ClassNotFoundException

Because i forgot

```
coll = new ArrayList<ColReteral>();
```

..